# Creating A Cookie

Tags: php

I am trying to use cookies to maintain log-in persistence on my website. But, for some reason unknown to me, the cookie is not being created. Only the Session is being created. I am using Sessions to keep track of the logged in user, and cookies to re-create the session when they come back. What am I doing wrong?

Create the session and cookie:

```
<?php

$connect= // connect variables

    $query= "SELECT * FROM users where email= '$email' AND password=    
'$password'";
    $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query)
        or die('error with query');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id']= $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['name']= $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];
            setcookie('id', $row['user_id']);
            $profile_url= 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/profile.php';
            header('Location:profile.php');     
            }
        else {
            $message= "Incorrect email/password combination.";
            }

?>
```

Check for a cookie to restore the session:

```
<?php

session_start()
/* if a session does not exist, see if a cookie does to set the session */
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
    }
    else {

    }
}

?>
```

**EDIT**

I needed to add an expiration parameter to the cookie!

```
setcookie('id', $row['user_id'],time()+86400);
Note: The above example sets the cookie for 1 day
```

Comment: Sorry :S Didn't know there was a timer :o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookie is created, but you create it for 0 seconds. Third parameter is $expire, use it...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

$expire quote

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will
>   set the cookie to expire in 30 days. **If set to 0, or omitted, the
>   cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser
>   closes).**

Comment: Thank you for your help! Condescending or not! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a few things here (expiry,path,domain):

```
setcookie('id', $row['user_id'],time()+86400,"/",".your_domain.com");
```

Note: The above example sets the cookie for 1 day in the root of the domain, for the domain "your_domain.com". Now thats a lot of domains!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add an expiration date to the cookie.

```
setcookie('id', $row['user_id'],time()+86400);
```

Comment: +1 @minitech Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I didn't notice it was the asker.